# Prove that $e>2$ geometrically.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, exponential-function

**Q:** Prove that $e>2$ geometrically.

**Attempt:** I only know one formal definition of $e$ that is $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n=e$. I could somehow understand that this is somehow related to rotation in the complex plane.
$$e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$$
Hence we have $$e^{i\pi}=-1$$
But how can I bring out the value of $e$ when I am showing this rotation in a geometrical figure?

Any hints are appreciated.

**EDIT:** As per the comments, I am making a small addition to the question which will not affect the existing answers. It is that, as a definition of $e$, one can use any definition which does not use the fact $2<e<3$.

Comment: Does this help? :   Look at the area under $\frac 1x$ from $[1,2]$. That is clearly less than $1$.  Thus, defining $e$ as the solution to $ln(x)=1$, we must have $e>2$.

Comment: @lulu: please post your answers in the "answer" box.

Comment: @lulu Okay but is this a geometrical proof?

Comment: @Aniket it is geometrical in the sense that "the area under a graph" is a geometrical measurement

Comment: @Omnomnomnom But we are measuring it by integration, isn't it?

Comment: @Aniket  Well, I'd say so...but of course it depends on what you mean by "geometric".  Also, it seems "natural" or not...depending on how you define "e".  Personally, I start with the definition via the natural log.  If you start from the power series then it is clear that $e>2$ but that's hardly geometric...

Comment: A nice approach would be to somehow show that $(1 + \frac 1n)^n$ is increasing as $n \to \infty$, then simply observe that
$$
\left(1 + \frac 11 \right)^1 = 2
$$
there are nice proofs of this fact, but I don't know if any of them are particularly "geometrical".

Comment: @lulu I think by geometry, the asker wanted me to draw some figure and use geometrical properties and some theorems and perform special constructions to prove this. I don't know the answer, but I'm guessing the asker , i.e. the interviewer wanted me to proceed in this way.

Comment: @Aniket since when are calculus and geometry mutually exclusive?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I don't know, but whenever I hear geometry, Euclidean geometry first comes to my head .... and then the cartesian with the calculus involved.

Comment: @Aniket  Well, you need some definition of $e$ in order to prove anything at all...and every definition that leaps to mind involves some "calculus-like" operation (integration, as in my area, power series, limit, as in your definition, differential equation, and so on).  To me, my construction is as geometric as you're going to get!  But, then, there are so many ways to look at $e$ that I wouldn't rule anything out.

Comment: @lulu I agree. You are totally right.

Comment: I don't think popular-math tag is suitable for your question. The tag-info says "Question on bits and pieces of mathematics that show up in popular media (TV, movies, comics, etc.)".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: perhaps [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1582706) qualifies.

Comment: I don't think it matters which definition of e you know.  We can assume basic *results*, such as the derivative exp x is exp x, and the integral of 1/x is ln x.  These are *results* that would be verified (in different ways for different defs) regardless of actual value.  So I really like lulu's.  I was going to do something about a tangent line to exp x but lulu's is better.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In this image

[image]

we see that
$$
\color{#00A000}{1}+\color{#C000C0}{x}\le\left(1+\frac x2\right)^2
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
1+1
&\le\left(1+\frac12\right)^2\\
&\le\left(1+\frac14\right)^4\\
&\le\left(1+\frac18\right)^8\\
&\dots\\
&\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{2^n}\right)^{\large2^n}\\[9pt]
&=e
\end{align}
$$

Comment: how did you produce the image?

Comment: @jkabrg: With [Intaglio](http://www.purgatorydesign.com/Intaglio/).

Comment: Nice moustache, robjohn! :-)

Comment: @mvw: Thanks! The hats just don't seem to fit a mean square.

Comment: @robjohn why does $\left(1+\frac12\right)^2 \le\left(1+\frac14\right)^4$ ?

Comment: Square the inequality for $x=\frac12$.

Answer (score 9):

A better (or at least alternative) definition of $e$ is this:

Let 
$$ L(x) = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} dt
$$
$L$ is well-defined for positive $x$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

With a little work, you can show that $L$ is surjective onto $R$, and since it's clearly increasing and continuous, it's also injective. So it has an inverse, $E$. $L$ is usually known as $\ln$ and $E$ is known as $\exp$.

Then $e = E(1)$ defines a new constant, called Euler's constant.

To show $e > 2$, you need only show that $L(2) < 1$. You can do this by computing an upper bound for the integral that is $L(2)$, i.e $\int_1^2 \frac{1}{t} dt$, using the partition $1, 1.5, 2$; and the left-hand ends as sample points (because $y = 1/x$ is a decreasing functions. The upper integral is then 
$$
\frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{5}{6} < 1,
$$
and you are done, because the integral is no larger than any of its upper integrals.

Comment: You're right; I was picturing log in my head as I wrote that, rather than $y = 1/x$. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

A simple geometrical representation can be given noting that $e=f(1)$ for a function $f(x)$ such that $f'(x)=f(x)$ and $f(0)=1$ (This can be a definition of $e$ derived from  the definition of the exponential function as the function that represents an exponential growth).

So, representing a graphical approximation of the function (a representation of the Euler Method),  as in the figure, We can see that $f(1)=e>2$

[image]

Comment: how did you produce this image?

Comment: Using LaTex with :http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 4):

You can give a (hyper)geometical interpretation to the inequality

$$(1+x)^n\gt 1+nx\quad\text{when }n\ge2$$

by viewing the left hand side as the volume of an $n$-dimensional hypercube with sides of length $1+x$ and the right hand side as the sum of the volumes of the unit hypercube and the $n$ hyperrectangles of size $1\times1\times\cdots\times1\times x$.  Plugging in $x=1/n$ leads to the inequality $e\gt2$.

Comment: I tried to carry off [a similar idea](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1582706) in two-dimensions that could be iterated.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)$ is a convex function, then:

$$f(x + h) \geq f(x) + h f'(x)~\forall x, \forall h > 0. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$

---

We know that the function $f(x) = e^x$ has an important geometrical property:

> the slope in any point is equal to the function itself

Also, we know that $f(x)$ is positive because of exponentiation. This implies that it is convex, since $f(x)'' = f'(x) =  f(x) > 0$ **(thanks to A.S. for this point)**.

Then, (1) holds for $f(x) = e^x$. That is:

$$f(x + h) \geq f(x) + h f'(x)~\forall x, \forall h > 0 \Rightarrow \\
f(x + h) \geq (1+h)f(x)~\forall x, \forall h > 0.$$

If we choose $x=h=1$, then:

$$f(2) \geq 2f(1) \Rightarrow \\
e^2 \geq 2e \Rightarrow \\
e \geq 2.$$

Comment: @A.S. yeah, you are right. I'm going to fix this.

Comment: @A.S. thanks again, I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fact that $e^x$ is its derivative:
$$
\int\limits_a^b e^x \, dx = e^b - e^a
$$
So
$$
e - 1 
= \int\limits_0^1 e^x dx 
= \int\limits_0^1 \left(1 + (\underbrace{e^x - 1}_{\ge 0}) \right) dx 
> \int\limits_0^1 1\, dx = 1
$$
So $e - 1$ can be interpreted as the area beneath the curve $e^x$ from $x = 0$ to $x = 1$. This area can be divided into the area below the constant function $f(x) = 1$ (green square) and some non-zero area which corresponds to the area below the function $g(x) = e^x - 1 \ge 0$ (the area having the points $A$, $B$, $D$).

[image: Area beneath the surface]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjtwQ.png))

Comment: how did you produce this image?

Comment: @jkabrg I used GeoGebra. A very nice software. I use version 5 with 3D support on Win 7 and iOS 9 and version 4 on Linux.

Comment: cheers, i'll check that out